# In propositional logic, why are there two implies?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I tried looking it up but I lack the English terminology to do so.

I do not understand the difference in $\models$ and $\vdash$ in propositional logic, I thought there was a difference until I saw this theorem:
$$\Sigma \models A \iff \Sigma \vdash A$$

But not, unsure.

The $\models$ means that we can for every assignment $M$ that satisfy all the forumlas in $\Sigma$. It means $M$ also satisfy $A$.

The $\vdash$ means that we have a "proof" of $A$ using $\Sigma$, but I really didn't understand what does that mean.

Can someone explain or link a place where I can read and understand the difference?

Comment: Basically, *syntax* is about rules for manipulating *symbols*, while *semantics* is concerned with the *meaning* of the statements. Of course, these *different methods* for deriving new statements should agree as much as possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\Sigma\vdash A$ does indeed mean that there is a formal proof of $A$ from the axioms on $\Sigma$.

What a formal proof is, is too big a subject to answer in an MSE answer, but any introductory text in logic ought to present at least one concept of formal proof, where you can see how everything fit together.

The fact that $\vDash$ (defined in terms of models) and $\vdash$ (defined in terms of proofs) are equivalent is not obvious and is a moderately deep result. It is involved enough that the two directions have separate names:

$\Sigma\vdash A \implies \Sigma\vDash A$ is the **soundness theorem** for the logic you're working with. (In other words, the proof system is "sound" if everything it proves is also actually true in every model).

$\Sigma\vDash A \implies \Sigma\vdash A$ is the **completeness theorem** for the logic. (A proof system is "complete" if a sentence that is true in every model has a proof).

Comment: Does the theorem implies that "everything we prove is true" and "everything that is true is provable" ?

Comment: @Rab: Yes, those are terser formulations of the soundness and completeness theorems. (Beware that they can be somewhat misleading unless one is aware that "true" is to be interpreted as "satisfied by every model").

Comment: Is that true for any $\Sigma$ though? because as far as I understand, we can have in $\Sigma$ things like not $\alpha$ and $\alpha$, or do we put a constrain on $\Sigma$

Comment: @Rab: Yes, that works for any $\Sigma$. If $\Sigma$ contains such a contradiction, then there are _no_ truth assignments that satisfy $\Sigma$, so $\Sigma\vDash A$ holds vacuously no matter what $A$ is. On the other hand, a complete proof system will allow _anything_ to be derived from $\neg\alpha\land\alpha$, so the correspondence still holds.